# Что будет с объектом после завершения работы

Tags: java

У меня есть такой код:

```
public class MainFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {

        SwingWorker bgUpdate;  
...

private void UpdateFromRemoteButtMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                                  

        bgUpdate = new SwingWorker() {

            @Override
            protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {

      /* код выполняемый в фоне */

            }
}

bgUpdate.addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {

            @Override
            public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                  /* код по завершению фонового задания */
                }
            }
        });

bgUpdate.execute();

}

}
```

Вот собственно о чём  я переживаю, так не будет ли засоряться память каждый раз когда я нажимаю на кнопку и запускаю фоновый поток. Или же после завершения фонового потока обЪект удалиться? Или же каждый раз когда я нажимаю на кнопку старый данные о старом обьекте удаляются а на их месте создаються данные о новом обьекте? Не переполню ли я физ. память после тысячного нажатия на кнопку?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Кратко: нет.

Подробно. В Java существует механизм сборки мусора. Он отвечает за удаление из памяти неиспользуемых объектов. Неиспользуемым объект считается тогда, когда он недоступен по ссылкам из текущей точки выполнения программы. Сборщик мусора запускается автоматически когда память близка к заполнению. Если в эти моменты на ваш `SwingWorker` нет ссылок, то он его удалит. Так как вы каждый раз при вызове `UpdateFromRemoteButtMouseClicked` вешаете на поле `bgUpdate` новый объект, ссылка на старый пропадает (я предполагаю, что вы не храните ссылки на `SwingWorker`, созданный в `UpdateFromRemoteButtMouseClicked`, в других местах вашего кода), следовательно, он подлежит удалению и не будет висеть в памяти после сборки мусора.

Comment: Дабы не создавать новую тему, спрошу в комментарии. У меня в этом же примере в фоном задании идёт заполнение БД. Что будет с потоком и самой базой данных если я в момент её заполнения закрою программу. Потом сам корректно завершится, или же лучше добавить функцию завершения потока перед закрытием дабы не повредить целостность БД?

Comment: Зависит от типа потока. Обычный поток продолжит выполняться после завершения основного потока. Поток-демон после завершения всех потоков не-демонов будет принудительно завершён. В случае работы с базой данный не стоит полагаться только на это, работу с базой следует производить в рамках транзакций, чтобы в случае неожиданного завершения приложения не повредить данные.